# SQL CASE statement to check multiple spellings in Field and return same value if found?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, toad, oracle12c

I am in the process of creating an Oracle DB conversion script to move records from an old singular table to a new table with more fields as well as child/reference tables for better integrity. When I run a `SELECT DISTINCT` for `VENDOR` in my Table1, I get back 58 results. An example of how varied these results are for the same meaning is below:

- WWT
- &nbspWWT
- Worldwide Technologies
- &nbspWorldwide Technologies
- WorldWide Technology
- World Wide Technology

In my reference table, I have already setup a record for this particular value as `"World Wide Technology, Inc."`

Is there a way I can specify (maybe a CASE statment?) that when these various spellings are used to return the value I have in my child table with (ex.) `"World Wide Technology, Inc."`?

This Table is the simplest child table to tackle as it only has 17 distinct values I've plugged into it, whereas Table1 has 58 distinct rows returning. So far I have:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (VendorID, col2, col3, col4, etc...)
SELECT T3.ID, T1.col7, T1.col8, T1.col9, etc...
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON LTRIM(UPPER(T1.Vendor)) = UPPER(T3.Vendor_Name)
```

I've got 1349 records in Table1, but this (for just the SELECT portion) is only returning 418 records.

Does anyone know how to go about what I'm after here?

Comment: Can you create a look-up table for the duration of your migration? If it has two columns, one containing all the distinct values from the old table, the other the sane value from your new look-up table (which would be duplicated), you could then join on that, and drop it when you've finished? Otherwise yes, you could use a big case statement to do the same thing.

Comment: I'd really prefer not to get into extra tables if possible. Would you be able to provide an example with the CASE statement in this scenario to get me started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have and don't want to create a mapping table, the case approach would be similar to your earlier question about dates. To convert all values you'd do something like:

```
select case
  when vendor in (
    'WWT',
    ' WWT',
    'Worldwide Technologies',
    ' Worldwide Technologies',
    ' WorldWide Technology',
    'World Wide Technology'
  ) then 'World Wide Technology, Inc.'
  when t1.vendor in (
    'ACME',
    ' acme'
  ) then 'ACME, Inc.'
  ... other groups of original values with their new equivalents
  else null
  end as vendor_name
from t1;
```

In your case you'd probably hard-code the new `vendor_id` rather than the name, otherwise you'd just have to join back to `t3` to get the ID based on your mapped name:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (VendorID, col2, col3, col4, etc...)
SELECT case
  when t1.vendor in (
    'WWT',
    ' WWT',
    'Worldwide Technologies',
    ' Worldwide Technologies',
    ' WorldWide Technology',
    'World Wide Technology'
  ) then 42 -- ID for 'World Wide Technology, Inc.'
  when t1.vendor in (
    'ACME',
    ' acme'
  ) then 76 -- ID for 'ACME, Inc.'
  ... other groups of original values with their new equivalents
  else null
  end as vendor_id, T1.col7, T1.col8, T1.col9, etc...
FROM Table1 T1;
```

If you have a lot of distinct values that only differ by case and leading/trailing whitespace, you could reduce the number of values to check with something like:

```
select case
  when trim(upper(t1.vendor)) in (
    'WWT',
    'WORLDWIDE TECHNOLOGIES',
    'WORLD WIDE TECHNOLOGY'
  ) then 42 -- ID for 'World Wide Technology, Inc.'
  when trim(upper(t1.vendor)) in (
    'ACME'
  ) then 76 -- ID for 'ACME, Inc.'
  else null
  end as vendor_name
from t1;
```

You could potentially also remove punctuation etc.. Basically whatever query expression you use to identify the distinct values in the first place has to match whatever you use in the case expressions. So in this example, rather than your original `SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR FROM Table1` which got 58 values you'd do `SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(UPPER(VENDOR)) FROM Table1` which will give you fewer, reducing (slightly) the pain of manually matching each one to a new vendor ID.

If you want to use the description in the case mappings, you can join to your new look-up table, and then do the case in the join clause:

```
select t1.vendor, t3.vendor_id, t3.description
from t1
left join t3 on t3.description = case
  when trim(upper(t1.vendor)) in (
    'WWT',
    'WORLDWIDE TECHNOLOGIES',
    'WORLD WIDE TECHNOLOGY'
  ) then 'World Wide Technology, Inc.'
  when trim(upper(t1.vendor)) in (
    'ACME'
  ) then 'ACME, Inc.'
  else null
  end;

VENDOR                    VENDOR_ID DESCRIPTION               
------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------
 Worldwide Technologies          42 World Wide Technology, Inc.
 World Wide Technology           42 World Wide Technology, Inc.
WWT                              42 World Wide Technology, Inc.
 AcMe                            76 ACME, Inc.
```

etc. This is just a demo, obviously. I've made it a left join so if you have a value you haven't mapped, or have a typo in a description, etc. it will try to insert a null value. You could then either look for nulls and fill them in as needed, or have a no-null constraint on your new (foreign key, presumably) column so it won't let you insert without a match - but that might be too restrictive, again depending on your actual data.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll give it a shot! And yea, I was just considering what you mention in your EDIT. I'm not sure if it would be any easier to have the script look up the ID of the desired value, or just hardcode the ID value in at the end of the CASE.

Comment: if you need it more than once, you can write a function using this. and you can use TRIM and UPPER to include leading and trailing spaces and differences in case.

Comment: Personally I'd probably use a query to list all the values and set up the case clauses directly from that, rather than edit the list so it can be used with trim and/or upper (or manually type the values); but yes, that is an option. It depends on the volume of data I suppose.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thanks! This example seems to have done the trick. Would you mind EDITING in an example of this other method you and 1010 are mentioning? For this child table (Vendors) there were only 58 distinct values that had to cased for the correct value, but for my (Models) child table  there are vastly more to contend with.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic - I've added a variation using trim and upper, which I think covers off what 1010 and I were talking about. How much it helps you depends on your actual data though.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thanks Alex! To kind of expand upon this, like with what I mentioned where `[Model]` has about 350 distinct values for this conversion, do you know a way to do the comparison, if match  -> set the general value I'd like used, and then use that value to find the relevant ID in the other table and set that as the value? Roughly -- CASE [MacbookAir], [MacbookPro]) THEN 'Macbook' => Find ID for record in [Models] that matches 'Model_Desc' of 'Macbook' and set as Model_ID? I could do the same here and set the ID explicitly in long script, but that just feels..dirty. Surely a better way?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic - OK, last update *8-) I've added a version that uses the descriptions in the case statement, and joins to you look-up table to get the IDs. Either way you're hard-coding one of the values from your look-up, but maybe you're happier being able to spot mistakes in a name than in a less obvious number.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thanks so much for your help and taking the time to teach me some of this stuff! =)  I'll give your updated suggestion a try and see what I come out with -- worst case I'll use the original CASE/Set ID scenario but I'm liking the initial look of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Lets then assume that you have a mapping table `Table4` with columns `wrong` to represent a mispelling of the entity you want and `right` to represent the correct spelling. Then:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (VendorID, col2, col3, col4, etc...)
SELECT COALESCE ( T4.RIGHT, T3.ID, T1.Vendor ), T1.col7, T1.col8, T1.col9, etc...
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 T3 ON LTRIM(UPPER(T1.Vendor)) = UPPER(T3.Vendor_Name)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 T4 ON LTRIM(UPPER(T1.Vendor)) = UPPER (T4.WRONG)
```

The `JOIN` will include all records from `T1` and results from `T3` or `T4` only where the match condition in either `JOIN` is met. Where the condition is not met, all `T3`/`T4` columns will appear to be `NULL` in the query results. Thus, you could use `COALESCE` in the `SELECT` clause to say: if there is a `T4.right`, use that, otherwise if there is a `T3.ID`, use that, otherwise, use `T1.Vendor`.

Comment: Ok, that is returning all 1349 rows now! But what about the issue of there being no match due to all the different spellings? How would I (assuming a CASE statement?) go about checking the multiple spellings and if found returning/inserting the value I want from the child table? Like if `VENDOR = WWT` I'd want the Vendor.ID to match the ID in my other table where the `VENDOR_NAME = World Wide Technologies, Inc.`?

Comment: Don't you have all of the alternative spellings in T3? If not, why not?

Comment: The old database using the singular table is a mess with different spellings for the same value, etc. I've set up these child/reference/lookup tables in addition to my main NEW table in order to better set some DB Integrity. Instead of just entering random Text, users will be forced either to select from those available values in the reference table, or create a new one there to select it. Ultimately it will be user discretion to create new/select from the list, but in this case these multiple values all reference the SAME entity and should have 1 value to represent it--not multiple spellings.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the function of `T3`. Perhaps you need a `T4` to map the alternative spellings to the proper entity.

Comment: Surely there must be a way to check the spellings for the INSERT and (if found) INSERT the ID of the value I actually want represented in the field?